# Select all cipher suites except those using ECDSA

Tags: openssl

I am trying to select all cipher suites except ECDSA ones with [`SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html) and [`SSL_set_cipher_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html). According to the documentation I am supposed to use the string `"ALL:!ECDSA"`. When I check it and run:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!ECDSA'
```

But this still includes suites with ECDSA, ie:

```
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

Any idea how to do it? I am using openssl 1.0.2g. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting... I can duplicate it in 1.0.2, but its *not* present in 1.1.0. And *`"HIGH:!aNULL:!ECDSA:!RC4:!MD5"`* may be a little better than using *ALL*.

Comment: Yeah, smells like a bug to me as well.